# What happened to levels 11-20 in the mystic class?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, class, mystic

I am referring to the mystic class presented in Unearthed Arcana. As far as I know it's not a prestige class like the rune scribe.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 9):

## It only had the levels 11-20 in the third iteration

The first two releases (articles [here](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/awakened-mystic)<sup>1</sup> and [here](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/psionics-and-mystic-%E2%80%93-take-two)) only had level 1 to 10. For the [third](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/mystic-class) iteration it was extended to level 20, as noted in the article:

> [T]he class now goes to level 20, has six subclasses, and can choose from many new psionic disciplines and talents.

---

1: Note that the article has been updated to link to the second version.